# Unable to run simple program of maven from Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, testing, selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

I have maven project just written Hello in it.

Process 1:
If I goto Project in top bar >> than click on clean and right click on project name >> Run as >> Maven test ...it works and gives output

Process 2: 
If I right click on project name >> Run as >> Maven clean>> again right click on project name >> Run as >> Maven test......it fails and gives

**[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?**

Why process two is not working?

Note: I have added JDK in java>> Installed JREs>> Execution environment

Environment:Ubuntu with Java openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14

Comment: Seems to be you don't have JDK on your machine/ system PATH Environment variable. Check if you have JDK on the machine and the environment variable does pointing to the `..jdk/bin`

Comment: @supputuri can you please help . I have JDK on my system also I have installed maven....path for JDK is                                                                               /usr/share/doc/default-jdk                           
/usr/share/doc/openjdk-11-jdk